# Matrix Inverse Proof $A^2 − 3A + I = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

If an (n × n) matrix $A$ satisfies the equation $A^2 − 3A + I = 0$ , where I is the (n × n)
identity - matrix, prove that $A$ has an inverse.

My attempt so far 
$A^2 − 3A + I = 0$
 $A^2 − 3A  = 0$
 $A(A − 3+ I) = 0$

<strike>Would the next step to include A on both sides?</strike>

Edit: I appreciate the answers, I realized due to misreading the question "where I is the (n × n) identity" $-3A$ is actually $-3AI$

Hence when factored:
$A^2 − 3A + I = 0$
$A^2 − 3AI + I = 0$ 
$A(A − 3I) = I$
$A-3I = A^{-1}$

Comment: Hint: $A^2-3A+I = 0 \implies A(3I-A) = I$.

Comment: How would $3I$ be achieved?

Comment: $3A  = 3AI = A(3I)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix such that $B^2 + B - I = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83715/matrix-such-that-b2-b-i-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^2-3A+I=0 \Rightarrow I=3A-A^2 \Rightarrow I=(3I-A)A \Rightarrow A^{-1}=3I-A$.

Comment: What about right inverse of A?

Comment: At least for finite matrices, when the left inverse exists, it's also a right inverse.

Comment: @Tojrah, $3I-A$ and $A$ commute.

Answer (score 2):

Here your question is "prove that **$A$ has an inverse**". For this you have to show that $ det (A) \neq 0$.

Now since $A$ satisfies the polynomial equation $ x^{2} − 3x + 1 = 0$ (as $A^{2} − 3A + I = 0 $ is given), which contains non-zero constant term $1$ so $ det (A) = 1 \neq 0$. Therefore $A$ has an inverse. [Q.E.D]

** Now if you have to find $A^{-1}$, then you can proceed as follows

$A^{2} − 3A + I = 0 $ .......(1)

Since A has an inverse, so multiplying both side of equation (1) by $A^{-1}$ we have

$A^{-1} (A^{2} − 3A + I) = A^{-1}. 0 \implies A^{-1} . A^{2} -3 A^{-1}. A + A^{-1} .I=0 \implies A - 3I + A^{-1}=0 \implies A^{-1} = 3I-A $