# Linear algebra find the inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a the following question:

> Given that $A$ is a square matrix that satisfies $A^2 - 3A + I = 0$, find the inverse of $A$.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Well, if $A B=I$ and $BA=I$, by definition $B=A^{-1}$; can you get your equation to look like this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208402/matrix-inverse-proof-a2-%E2%88%92-3a-i-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You're given

$$\;A^2-3A+I=0\implies A(A-3I)=-I\;\ldots$$

Comment: Missed a minus sign

Comment: @EuxhenH True. Thanks, edited.

Comment: How will that negative sign affect the (A - 3I)? Supposing that's the inverse

Comment: @DavidMeléndez Well, if for matrices $\;A,\,B\;$ you have that $\;AB=-I\;$ , then (by linearity of matrices) you get $\;A(-B)=I\;$ .