# Proving that a Matrix has an Inverse using a Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose an $(n × n)$ matrix $A$ satisfies that an equation such as, $A^{2} − 3A + I = 0,$ where $I$ is the $(n × n)$
identity-matrix, prove that A has an inverse.

Any tips on approaching a proof?

Comment: Try rearranging the equation.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83715/matrix-such-that-b2-b-i-0?rq=1), with a slightly different equation, which goes exactly the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$A(3I-A) = 3A-A^{2} =I$$

Also $$(3I-A)A=3A-A^{2}=I$$

Thus $$A^{-1}= 3I-A$$ therefore $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$ A(A-3I) = A^2 -3 A = -I $$
I assume you can finish from here.